# Getting `error TS2304: Cannot find name '<type>'` with ts-node compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have this in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "ts",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modues"]
}
```

I have this folder structure:

```
src/
  scripts/
    doX.ts
  types/
    number.d.ts
```

In `number.d.ts` I have:

```
type int8 = number
```

In `doX.ts`, I have:

```
function add8(a: int8, b: int8) {
  return a + b
}

const x: int8 = add8(1, 2)
```

I am getting no errors in VSCode, but when I do the following I get an error:

```
$ npx ts-node src/scripts/doX.ts 
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/scripts/doX.ts:... - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'int8'.

... function add(a: int8, b: int8) {
                    ~~~~     ~~~~
```

What am I missing to get `ts-node` to compile and run this properly?

Comment: Please keep in mind that TS has structural type system: `type int8 = number` and `type int16 = number` are the same

Comment: I have that in mind, thank you :)

Comment: I can help you but if you publish it in github